# Batch JSON to Features help

Tags: arcpy, json, batch

I have a folder on my local drive with 1,500+ JSON files (lines) that I need converted to shapefiles. (JSON to feature tool in ArcGIS works great on a single JSON file)

I've tried getting a batch model in Python to work, but this code seems to give me an ERROR 000206 after 31 JSON files...

Any ideas?

(I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 and PyScripter)

```
import arcpy
import os

dirOfJSON = 'c:/temp/jsons'
outputDIrectory = 'c:/temp/jsonSHPs'

arcpy.env.workspace = dirOfJSON

for f in arcpy.ListFiles('*.json'):
    j = os.path.join(dirOfJSON, f)
    outputShp = os.path.join(outputDIrectory, os.path.splitext(f)[0] + '.shp')
    print("Processing : {}".format(outputShp))
    arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(j, outputShp)
```

Comment: There seems no error in code, it is working properly in my system. There must be some error in naming convention of folder or json files.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked for me also, however I'm not processing over 1,500 .json files. Is the 32nd .json file name incorrectly? Did your .gdb reach a storage limit?

Answer (score 4):

Based on that [error code](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp0000000n000206) it looks like you're trying to create a feature class and giving it a name with illegal characters.

> `000206 : Cannot create FeatureClass <value>`.
>
> The named feature class cannot be created as named.
>
> Solution
>
> The name that has been specified is likely invalid. Correct the name
>   and try again. All data formats have characters that are considered
>   invalid and should not be used as feature class names. Rename the
>   feature class using characters that are valid for the underlying
>   database. In addition to spaces, the following list contains
>   characters that should not be used in a geodatabase feature class
>   name: `~@#$%^&*()-+|\,<>?{}.!'[]:;. If working in Python, ArcPy has
>   functions that allow you to validate table names and field names. **You
>   can use the ValidateTableName or ValidateFieldName functions to ensure
>   that the name is valid.**

Comment: Jeff, this is not the case. My files are named _PL123_ _PL456_ _PL789_. I am not using any characters besides letter and numbers.